# Angular Material Calendar set always focus on today's date day

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar

Whenever I click on any date on Angular Material Calendar, today's date tile is heighlighted. Even it is in an other month, the day is highlighted.

Is this a bug or a feature ? I say feature, because even in documentation exemple this is reproductible.

Here is some code for reference and the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ltsxx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-inline-calendar-example.ts)

```
<mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>

import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker inline calendar example */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-inline-calendar-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerInlineCalendarExample {
  selected: Date | null;
}
```

It looks like the day get a focus when calendar is clicked. Also, it seems be true only in Safari.

How to shortcut the bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The StackBlitz link is broken btw. It seems reasonable to highlight today's date for reference though.

Comment: Yes, but not the 24th of January, or 24th of March, etc

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Ya, that looks buggy.

Comment: I fixed the link. Also, it is probably only on Safari

Answer (score 0):

As per Angular Material documentation, there is no property to set the current date selection to be hidden. Therefore I assume it is a feature put in by the angular developer team.

> Please find the angular official documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).

However, if you want to hide the selection of the current date from the user there is a workaround available via manipulating the `style.scss` of Angular.

**Please find the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ltsxx-islrjp?file=src/styles.scss).**

**By adding the below style to your `style.scss` you will be able to override the current selection :**

```
    .mat-calendar-body-today
      :not(.mat-calendar-body-selected)
      :not(.mat-calendar-body-comparison-identical) {
      background-color: rgb(255 255 255) !important;
      border: none !important;
    }
```

**In component HTML:**

```
<mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
<p>Selected date: {{selected}}</p>
```

**In component TS :**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Datepicker inline calendar example */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-inline-calendar-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-inline-calendar-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerInlineCalendarExample {
  selected: Date | null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already tied setting -today class properties with no success. I should have mentiend taht in my post. The issu is only in Safari. And it shows "today" on the today date() of every month  as shown in images of my post

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to shortcut the bug in Safari which made the day of today's date focused, whichever was the month.

```
.mat-calendar-body-active>.mat-calendar-body-cell-content.mat-focus-indicator{
    background:transparent !important
}
```

This removed the unnecessary focus on the day